# GDB not able to access memory

Tags: c++, gdb, c++17

I am trying an example in the documentation: "x/4wx 0x54320". I expect to see 16 hex characters. Instead I get an error: "Cannot access memory at address 0x54320".

According to documentation: "address is the address where you want GDB to begin displaying memory: it is always interpreted as an integer address of a byte of memory.".

Is GDB taking "0x54320" as the location to start looking, or the address (pointer) to the location to start looking?

Anyway, all I want is to see the bytes stored starting at "0x54320". How do I accomplish this, please?

Comment: How do you know `0x54320` is a valid address?

Comment: *"the location to start looking, or the address (pointer) to the location to start looking?"* -- what do you see as the difference between these two options? From my perspective, I see this similar to asking if "110 William Street" is a location or the address of a location.

Comment: I just want to see the hex bytes starting a some location in the address space of the debugee, which starts at 0, ends at FFFFFFFFFFFF. That is all. Forget about the semantics. How do I do that please?

Comment: I'd bet that `0x54320` is not a valid address, so it is inaccessible.  Are you sure that address is in the process space?  (I think with gdb it's `maintenance info sections`, with lldb it is `image dump sections`.)

Comment: I do not know that. What I am doing comes from an example in "10.6 Examining Memory", of documentation. It never mentions about the validity of address, or how to know it is valid.

Answer (score 0):

`x/4wx 0x54320` is incorrect.  You probably mean `x/4xw 0x54320`: display 4 words as hex beginning at address 0x54320.  If that address is a pointer, you'll see the value of the pointer, i.e., the address it holds.

`0x54320` looks suspicious to me.  It's a rare address that just happens to count down in hex.  But, maybe you're just lucky.

Comment: I tried 4xw, same result: Error. I changed address to 0x0, no change in response from GDB. How can an address be invalid? I am asking GDB to print the bytes starting at some address, where ever that may be.

Comment: If that address is not in your address space, it's not a valid address.  You're not on a real machine (probably) with addresses 0 to <max RAM>.  Your program is executing in an isolated process in virtual memory managed by the operating system.

Comment: It is OK. I will keep trying, or give up. Basically, you are saying GDB command for memory has some very limited use. The address space I mentioned is virtual address space for a process. The debugee is a process. I could get what I am looking for via ptrace. I thought GDB should be able to do the same. How in the world I can tell some address is in fact valid from GDB's perspective, and why would that be useful anyway? I am interested in values stored anywhere in the address space of the process I am debugging, not what GDB thinks to be valid?

Comment: I use gdb every day.  I'm not saying the x command is of limited use, not at all.  I'm saying if gdb tells you the specified address is not valid, it's probably not valid.  It must be related to some symbol, right?  Print the address of the symbol, and subtract that address from the one you're looking at.  Is the difference less than the size of the object named by the symbol?  Work at it from that angle.  Good luck.

Comment: No James, the address does not belong to any symbol. Again, I want to see the bytes starting at some address, where-ever that may be. Is this possible? According to documentaiton, I am doing the right thing, but... By limited use I mean just that: you cannot just specify some random address, apparently it must be the address of some symbol. That is not useful, not for me anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @SohrabHonargohar You have to specify an address that the OS has mapped into the debugged process's virtual address space.  Trying to read from an unmapped address will result in the OS raising an error.  This isn't a limitation of GDB; unmapped virtual addresses are simply meaningless until the OS maps them to a physical memory location (or other memory-mapped I/O mechanism).

Comment: Documentation I am refering to is at: (https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html#Memory). The excellent comments here indicate that one needs a defined symbol to see its memory pattern. e.g. do "print &some_symbol", then use the address with x command to see it memory pattern. Great, that might have some uses. Then, I tried "x/4xw $sp" from documentation. I got "No symbol "nprint" in current context." and GDB froze. OK, let us try "x/4xw $rsp". Now I got 'Undefined command: "type".  Try "help".', and gdb froze again. Time to quit.